# SQL Server : send email

Tags: sql-server, email

I want to use SQL Server to send email and found two possible way from the internet:

1. Using AOSMTP.Mail

   ```
   Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[RC_SendEmail]  @ServerAddr varchar(80),
      @FromAddr varchar(80), 
      @Recipient varchar(80), 
      @Subject varchar(132),
      @BodyText varchar(2000)

   AS
     DECLARE @hr int
     DECLARE @oSmtp int
     DECLARE @nRet int

     EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'AOSMTP.Mail',@oSmtp OUT
     EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @oSmtp, 'RegisterKey', 'replace this text by your key'
     EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @oSmtp, 'ServerAddr', @ServerAddr
     EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @oSmtp, 'FromAddr', @FromAddr
     EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @oSmtp, 'AddRecipient', NULL, @Recipient, @Recipient, 0 
     EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @oSmtp, 'Subject', @Subject 
     EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @oSmtp, 'BodyText', @BodyText 

     EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @oSmtp, 'SendMail', @nRet OUT 
     EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @oSmtp
   ```

However, this method required a Server Address.

What is the address I am supposed to enter? the email server? or the database server?
I only see that it use 'localhost' in the internet. But it doesn't work for me.

1. Using CDONTS.NewMail

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendEmail] 
       @From varchar(100),
       @To varchar(100),
       @Subject varchar(100),
       @Body varchar(4000),
       @CC varchar(100) = null,
       @BCC varchar(100) = null
   AS
       Declare @MailID int
       Declare @hr int
       Declare @result int

       EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'CDONTS.NewMail', @MailID OUT
       EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @MailID, 'From',@From
       EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @MailID, 'Body', @Body
       EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @MailID, 'BCC',@BCC
       EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @MailID, 'CC', @CC
       EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @MailID, 'Subject', @Subject
       EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @MailID, 'To', @To
       EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @MailID, 'Send', @result OUT
       EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @MailID
       select @result
   ```

This one required no Server Address but it doesn't work as well.

Can anyone explain in more details about these and what I should do?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Forget that, use the send email capabilities built-in on SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/). It doesn't get any easier.

Once you configure it through the wizard, you can simply do this inside your procs, as shown in the tutorial linked:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='PinalProfile',
@recipients='test@Example.com',
@subject='Test message',
@body='This is the body of the test message.'
```