# ASP.NET Email Subscription

Tags: asp.net, email

I have a database of email subscribers; approx. 1800 in the list. We have our own exchange server. I'm using the code below to grab each email address from the DB and send email, one at a time. I'm using an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Form to do this.

I notice the page hanging when the emails are being sent. What would be the best approach for implementing this - use a console app? How would I go about stress testing something like this?

I'm also getting an unhandled error message in the server log:

Event code: 3001 
Event message: The request has been aborted.

```
// Call data access method via business class
TaxSalesBusiness bizClass = new TaxSalesBusiness();
DataSet ds = bizClass.GetSubscribers();

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    // Check well-formedness of each email adddress
    if (!IsWellformedEmailAddr(row["Email"].ToString()))
    {
        // Ignore and log mal-formed email address
        LogError(row["Email"].ToString() 
           + " is a malformed email address. Message was not sent to this subscriber " 
           + row["Name"].ToString() + ".", "");
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        string toAddress = row["Email"].ToString();
        smtpClient.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, message.Subject, message.Body); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I notice the page hanging when the emails are being sent. What would
>   be the best approach for implementing this - use a console app?

Yes.

And you can [`SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) instead of waiting for one email to be sent before you send the next one. I don't know how much your Exchange server will like that, though.

The problem with your current approach is that sending 1800 emails one by one is going to take a lot of time and using a web page to perform such a long operation will probably timeout the request. You can perhaps do it on an [`async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) page and launch everything on its own thread, but that's just complicating things more than it needs to when you can perfectly do this in a Console App with far less lines of code and complications. Remember the [`KISS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.

Comment: +1, thanks. What's the best way to test all emails being sent?

Comment: @IrishChietain: I imagine you ask because you want to send them asynchronously... You can keep a counter since you know in advance how many records you have(i.e. `int totalEmailsToSend=ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`). You can increase the counter when the callback method is invoked. Once they are both equal (totalEmailsToSend and your counter), you know you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Another (more stable) solution could be to forward the mails to a (database?) queue, and have a Windows Service poll that queue once in a while. If there are new things on the queue the Windows Service is responsible for sending the e-mails.

This approach will help you steer clear from performance issues in your website, and it could make the delivery of the mails to be more reliable.

Comment: This is a good point. If Sql Server is used, he can send the emails within Sql Server very easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265494/sql-server-send-email/7265512#7265512

Comment: Just to clarify: this list is email-blasted once every few years; emails are not being generated as a result of someone just subscribing for example. Also, am using SQL Server 2000 - so not sure about any email functionality limitations with that.