# How to call .aspx page from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to call an `aspx` page from SQL Server? I heard about this but no idea how to call?

In my case I have a SQL Job where I need to call `aspx` to execute certain tasks.

Comment: What do you mean by "call it"?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a SQL Job, by which i have to send mail with certain attachments? By calling aspx page i can execute this task easily.

Comment: How do you know you can do this easily if you don't even know how to do it?  I'm going to have to go with @TomTom's answer.

Comment: Check this link.  

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/compact-framework/16/9142/alling-aspx-page-from-sql-server-scheduled-job-.aspx

Comment: Actually, check this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument

Answer (score 3):

NOT AT ALL?

> In my case i have a SQL Job where i need to call aspx to execute certain tasks.

Fired for gross abuse. SQL Server is a database. SQL Server jobs (assuming you mean the jobs) is not a replacement for a decent scheduling system. It should not be used to run things like mail campaigns etc.

Rework your system to adhere to SQL Server as it is intended to use, not by making it look like an application server by pretty much abusing every feature possible.

Comment: I don't completely agree or disagree with your answer. There's not enough context to determine whether what the OP is looking for should be delegated to a different system or not, but I do think that sending emails from within SQL Server has valid business scenarios.

Comment: Yes. The valid business reason is stupid design by an incompatent person. Been there, seen it often enough. Want to do that really? Write a small program running on the server that gets called regularly by the windows scheduler. SQL Server is NOT an application server. Never was, never will be, but some developers dont see that even if hit on the head with a baseball bat repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a .NET assembly that performs the http call and load it in SQL Server so it can be accessed from there.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345106.aspx) about how you can create assemblies in SQL and [this one] that shows how to call .Net functions from such an assembly using T-SQL[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx).

One downside of this is that (as far as I know) there's no way to parameterize the URL to call (like in a config file). Every time the URL changes, you'll have to redeploy the assembly in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you need (send an email with attachments) from SQL Server without involving any loading of assemblies into SQL Server.

See this answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265494/sql-server-send-email/7265512#7265512) and the complete documentation of sp_send_dbmail [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Icarus, but i have to send more than one Excel/PDF attachments with email and i do not have any permission to generate new file in database server.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to call aspx page from SQL Server?

Yes, but please don't. It requires disabling native SQL Server security, and a bunch of other ugly things.

It's much better to do it the other way around. Have your web page call SQL Server to obtain the data it needs. You can even set that up using Service Broker notifications to you don't have to use polling.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call a page using

```
Declare @URL varchar(1000) 
Declare @Object as Int;
set @URL='your page URL'

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',@URL,'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
```