# generate email notification in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Currently I am doing leave management system.here,there are admin and user profiles.When user request a leave, email should be generated from back-end and send to admin  as notification that leave has been requested.Now I need query in sql

Comment: Hello, You should probably provide a lot more information.  This is super broad and everyone would only be guessing.  Maybe show your current ideas, what language you use, your design, etc.  edit:  But, apparently, others know what you mean, so I hope they can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server : send email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265494/sql-server-send-email)

Comment: http://sqlserverinformation.blogspot.in/2011/05/sending-e-mail-through-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, first of all you need to configure Database Mail and define a valid SMTP configuration, then you can call the SP
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name, @recipients, @body, @subject, @body_format;

please let me know if you need help configuring the database mail.